# What process state(s) is counted into cpu time?

Tags: linux, bash, process, linux-kernel, time

Two observations of mine (correct me if wrong):

- In the output of `time` for timing a process,

  > 'User' and 'Sys' come from wait (2) or times (2), depending on the particular system.
- In Linux kernel, both the process states "running" and "ready" (i.e. runnable and waiting in run queue) are represented by `TASK_RUNNING`.

What process state(s) counts into the cpu time of a process:

- "running"
- "ready"
- both "running" and "ready", i.e. `TASK_RUNNING` ?

My pick is "running". But if that is true, since `TASK_RUNNING` in Linux kernel  doesn't distinguish between "running" and "ready", how can `time` report the cpu time?

Answer (score 0):

For counting the time the important are the ticks of the processor and the ticks that the process wasted on the processor. If you're talking about the time a process spend on the processor you have to sum the ticks while running in user and kernel mode.